# Counting positive integral solutions to an equation(2)

Tags: combinatorics

This question related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553246/counting-positive-integral-solutions-to-an-equation). Question was to find integral solutions to,

> $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=13$
>
> where $1≤y_i≤8$ for each $i\in{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

For this, we applied a limit. $z_i=y_i−1$ . So the above question became integral solutions to

> $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5+z_6=7$
>
> where $0≤z_i≤7$ for each $i\in{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

In this question, the upper limit is not relevant now because there are no positive integral solutions when $z_i > 7$

Thus we solved it using the well known stars and bars formula for finding non-negative integral solutions

Suppose the question was to find integral solutions to

> $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=33$
>
> where $1≤y_i≤8$ for each $i\in{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

For this, if we applied a limit. $z_i=y_i−1$ , question becomes integral solutions to

> $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5+z_6=27$
>
> where $0≤z_i≤7$ for each $i\in{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

Then we cannot remove the upper limit as there can be solutions whre $z_i>7$

Can anyone guide me how to proceed further from this point? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reduced the problem of determining the number of solutions in the positive integers of the equation 
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 33 \tag{1}$$
subject to the restrictions that $y_i \leq 8$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ to the equivalent problem of determining the number of solutions in the nonnegative integers of the equation 
$$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 = 27 \tag{2}$$
subject to the restriction $z_i \leq 7$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.

Since $27$ is closer to $42 = 6 \cdot 7$ than $0 = 6 \cdot 0$, we can simplify the problem by setting $x_i = 6 - z_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.  Making these substitutions in equation 2 yields 
\begin{align*}
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 & = 27\\
6 - x_1 + 6 - x_2 + 6 - x_3 + 6 - x_4 + 6 - x_5 + 6 - x_6 & = 27\\
-x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - x_4 - x_5 - x_6 & = -15\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 15 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Since $x_i = z_i - 6$, equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with the restriction that $x_i \leq 6$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.

If there were no restrictions, the the number of solutions of equation 3 would equal the number of ways we could insert five addition signs into a row of fifteen ones, which can be done in $$\binom{15 + 5}{5} = \binom{20}{5}$$ ways since a particular solution is determined by selecting which five of the twenty symbols (five addition signs and fifteen ones) will be addition signs.

From these, we must remove those solutions in which one or more $x_i$'s exceed $6$.  Since $3 \cdot 7 = 21 > 15$, at most two of the $x_i$'s can exceed $6$ simultaneously.

Suppose $x_1 > 6$.  Let $t_1 = x_1 - 7$.  Then $t_1$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $t_1 + 7$ for $x_1$ in equation 3 yields
\begin{align*}
t_1 + 7 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 15\\
t_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 8 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $$\binom{8 + 5}{5} = \binom{13}{5}$$ solutions.  By similar argument, there are $\binom{13}{5}$ solutions in which $x_i > 6$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.  If we subtract these $$\binom{6}{1}\binom{13}{5}$$ solutions, we subtract those solutions in which two $x_i$'s exceed $6$ twice, so we must add those solutions back.

Suppose both $x_1$ and $x_2 > 6$.  Let $t_1 = x_1 - 7$; let $t_2 = x_2 - 7$.  Substituting $t_1 + 7$ for $x_1$ and $t_2 + 7$ for $x_2$ in equation 3 yields
\begin{align*}
t_1 + 7 + t_2 + 7 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 15\\
t_1 + t_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 1 \tag{5}
\end{align*}
Equation 5 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{5 + 1}{5} = \binom{6}{5}$$
solutions.  However, there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways in which two of the six variables exceed $6$.

Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), there are 
$$\binom{20}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{13}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{5}$$ solutions to equation 1 that satisfy the given restrictions.